# "Командировка" чи "відрядження"?

Tags: вибір-слова, росіянізм

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/komandyrovka) знаходжу значення слова **командировка**:

> **КОМАНДИРО́ВКА**, и, жін. Те саме, що **відрядження** 2—4. — Всього три дні був у командировці, а вже занудьгував за ними (Олесь Донченко, VI, 1957, 537); [Ольга:] Я піду.. в місто, пошукаю номер в готелі.. Дай мені твій паспорт — про всякий випадок і командировку (Іван Кочерга, II, 1956, 317).

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) також подає ці два слова:

> **ВІДРЯ́ДЖЕННЯ** (поїздка, пов’язана з службовим дорученням; посвідчення про таку поїздку), **КОМАНДИРО́ВКА** рідше. Інженери.. повертаються з відрядження (О. Довженко); Мигцем глянув у передане Ігорем відрядження, недбало кинув його на стіл (Ю. Шовкопляс); - Всього три дні був у командировці, а вже занудьгував (О. Донченко).

Однак, [Словник-антисуржик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/45/53402/299957.html) вказує, що слово **командировка** -це суржик:

> **КОМАНДИРОВКА**
>
> *відрядження*

Отже, чи є **командировка** нормативним словом, чи суржиком?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сучасний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах уже подає «командировка» як розмовне:

> **[КОМАНДИРО́ВКА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43119&page=1361)**, и, ж., розм[овне]. Те саме, що **відря́дження** 2, 3. — *Може, він поїхав кудись? Ну, звичайно, він поїхав у командировку! — зміркував професор* (В. Підмогильний); — *Всього три дні був у командировці, а вже занудьгував за ними* (О. Донченко); *Рано-вранці Явині батьки поїхали на кілька днів до Києва звітувати про свою закордонну командировку на Виставці передового досвіду* (В. Нестайко); *[Ольга:] Я піду .. в місто, пошукаю номер в готелі .. Дай мені твій паспорт — про всякий випадок і командировку* (І. Кочерга).

Відподвідно слово «відрядження» є бажанішим.

Трішки старіші [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) хоч і не позначають «командировка» як розмовне, але в переліку синонімів маркують його приміткою «рідше»:

> **ВІДРЯ́ДЖЕННЯ** (поїздка, пов'язана з службовим дорученням; посвідчення про таку поїздку), **КОМАНДИРО́ВКА** *рідше*. *Інженери.. повертаються з відрядження* (О. Довженко); *Мигцем глянув у передане Ігорем відрядження, недбало кинув його на стіл* (Ю. Шовкопляс); *— Всього три дні був у командировці, а вже занудьгував* (О. Донченко).